# What is the best practice for archiving Jenkins pipeline artifacts

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, nexus, artifacts

I see that you can add a goal to a maven Pom to archive artifacts to a repo manager such as nexus

https://www.baeldung.com/maven-deploy-nexus

```
distributionManagement>
   <snapshotRepository>
      <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
   </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

But Jenkins also allows you to do this from the pipeline itself

https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=96076078#content/view/96076078

```
freeStyleJob('NexusArtifactUploaderJob') {
    steps {
      nexusArtifactUploader {
        nexusVersion('nexus2')
        protocol('http')
        nexusUrl('localhost:8080/nexus')
        groupId('sp.sd')
        version('2.4')
        repository('NexusArtifactUploader')
        credentialsId('44620c50-1589-4617-a677-7563985e46e1')
        artifact {
            artifactId('nexus-artifact-uploader')
            type('jar')
            classifier('debug')
            file('nexus-artifact-uploader.jar')
        }
        artifact {
            artifactId('nexus-artifact-uploader')
            type('hpi')
            classifier('debug')
            file('nexus-artifact-uploader.hpi')
        }
      }
    }
}
```

What is the difference between the two approaches, is one more commonly used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is that if you use maven, you can manually add artifacts to Nexus from your local computer, using `mvn deploy`. So it really comes down to how you want to create the artifacts that end up being used in production. In my experience, the preferred way of doing this is through using Jenkins. The advantage of using Jenkins is that you link your new version builds to other activities, as well as the possibility to trigger a release when certain conditions have been met, rather than starting the build manually. Also, you end up with all versions being built on the same platform, and you avoid differences between computers if every developer builds such versions from their own computer.

But you might still need the maven configuration. Jenkins might use this information to find the URL to upload the artifact to (your example says nothing about how Jenkins finds Nexus), and sometimes it is useful to upload a SNAPSHOT-version, or some other temporary version not meant for production. In your example you only define Nexus for upload SNAPSHOT-versions, I guess this is done on purpose to enforce a rule that uploading final version from local computers is disallowed.

By the way, having a repository defined in your `pom.xml` does not automatically mean that anything will be uploaded. It is only if you do `mvn deploy` with a repository defined in your pom that something will be uploaded.

Comment: I'll try to clarify my question. What I am trying to understand is whether the 'deploy' is more suitable to be part of the pom or the jenkinsfile itself. Assume a situation where there is a repository called my-app and inside you have the usual structure for a java app created with maven. If the jenkinsfile and pom.xml both exist in the repo, what is the better practice for CI/CD? Publishing the artifact by setting 'deploy' goal (+repo url) in the POM? Or by setting the 'package' goal and using a jenkins plugin to push it to nexus? Is it just a personal preference or is there a best practice.

Comment: I would say this mostly comes down to personal preference. Only practical difference from what I can tell is how simple it would be to add artifacts to Nexus without using Jenkins. Some might like to be able  to do so, some might want to prevent people from doing it.

Comment: The simpler solution would be to rely on the pom.xml though, since maven will handle the upload for you. It also allows you to use maven release plugin (it's not that good, so not a big loss if you can't..) I'm not sure how easy it is to upload from Jenkins to Nexus without using maven to do so